# regular expression to match a dot before group with re.findall

Tags: python, regex

When I want to match a dot as literal in a string, it works when the escaped dot is followed by a literal, but not when it's followed by a re group.

```
>>> re.findall(r'\.de', 'abc.de')
['.de']
```

But with a group the dot is lost

```
>>> re.findall(r'\.(de|ab)', 'abc.de')
['de']
```

How can I re.findall `['.de']` with a group in my regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are capturing the wrong group :-)

```
re.findall(r'(\.(?:de|ab))', 'abc.de')

#or
# re.findall(r'\.(?:de|ab)', 'abc.de')
```

I have ignored your original group using `?:`

Comment: Do you actually need to add the outer pair of brackets? I only ask because OP said that `r'\.de'` worked.

Comment: If there is any group `(..)` in `re.findall()` then it returns the groups starting from `1,...`. But if there is no groups used then it returns the `group 0`. I have used the outer pair from my habit, but it will work without the pairs as well(in second example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The special character is called "non-capturing version of regular parentheses" (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I would also like to know why you added the outer pair of parenthesis, the result is the same with and without.

Comment: @KarlRichter it was written from the habit of using group capture. You can use the either ones without any worry.